# Confirm a sale quotation into a sale order with some quantities set to 0

Tags: odoo

In my custom sale quotation report I want to show some products with a 0 quantity and therefore have created sale order lines for some products with their quantities set to 0. It works fine and shows in the sale quotation report.

But when I confirm that same sale quotation into a sale order OpenERP throws the following message:

*"Data Insufficient !
Please check the quantity in procurement order(s), it should not be 0 or less!"*

How can I confirm an order with some quantities set to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to inherit the **Procurement** and then override the **action_confirm** method in your custom module.

In [procurement.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/procurement/procurement.py), find "def action_confirm()" on line: 320. Copy and past the whole method and remove those lines which raise the exception.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thank You.

Comment: Your method is nice and clean and I should really have a go at it. However I needed an urgent solution and I modified the procurement.py file to fit my requirements, and then recompiled it. It works fine now. But I will try the inheritance method which is a better way to do it IMO.

Comment: yes, you should do it in your module rather than modifing core module's code. If your problem is solved then you should accept my ans or if you have better solution then you should share it. Thank you.

Comment: Once I have created my custom procurement_custom.order view, inherited from procurement.order View, do I need to make sure it gets called by the sale.py (sale.order module) by modifying the trigger call line 846 from "procurement.order" to "procurement_custom.order"? Otherwise, how is my custom inherited view called when confirming an order?

Comment: class custom_procurement_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'procurement.order'
    def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None)
        #copy and past the code and remove exception part
        return True

You do not need to call super. Just copy and past the whole code except exception part.

Answer (score 1):

```
class procurement_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'procurement.order'
    def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
         move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')
        for procurement in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            #if procurement.product_qty <= 0.00:
                #raise osv.except_osv(_('Data Insufficient !'),_('Please check the quantity in procurement order(s), it should not be 0 or less!'))
            if procurement.product_id.type in ('product', 'consu'):
                if not procurement.move_id:
                    source = procurement.location_id.id
                if procurement.procure_method == 'make_to_order':
                    source = procurement.product_id.product_tmpl_id.property_stock_procurement.id
                id = move_obj.create(cr, uid, {
                    'name': procurement.name,
                    'location_id': source,
                    'location_dest_id': procurement.location_id.id,
                    'product_id': procurement.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty': procurement.product_qty,
                    'product_uom': procurement.product_uom.id,
                    'date_expected': procurement.date_planned,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'company_id': procurement.company_id.id,
                    'auto_validate': True,
                })
                move_obj.action_confirm(cr, uid, [id], context=context)
                self.write(cr, uid, [procurement.id], {'move_id': id, 'close_move': 1})
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirmed', 'message': ''})
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for the bit of code, I had that one already figured out by changing the  product_qty <= 0.00 to product_qty < 0.00.  What I can't figure out is the new view definition required to inherit from the procurement view and if I have to create an xml as well...

Comment: If you want to change the view then you need to inherit the view in your .xml, otherwise you don't need to inherit the view.